# Badge or reputation awarded after X viewed questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, badges

If I refresh a question (to check if there are news) the counter for the number of views goes up with +1. So, before that the suggestion as in the title of this question could be applied, it should change.

I'm thinking about a ratio about the moment a user registered and the number of questions that user actually viewed. For example, if I would register a new account today and after 3 months I read 2 questions, and one of these was mine, then I should be awarded either some negative badge or a - X reputation points decrease.

If I would register a new account and in 3 months I viewed 100 questions, then I should be awarded either some positive (good) badge or a + X reputation increase (because it seems that I would learn more before asking only).

What do you think about?

After the answers of @Aleanno and @NickCraver I would underline that the suggestion could be applied only to the "positive badge" or "positive reputation" and not for the negative badge/reputation.

I thought at good and bad badge/reputation because you could agree or disagree with some things. Similar to upvotes and downvotes!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Are you suggesting a system that "rewards" users for looking at a lot of posts before asking, and "penalizes" users that ask questions but don't read other user's questions first? (Or something like that.)

Comment: @Mat I think he's asking for that, more or less.

Comment: @ mat : yes you're right!

Answer (score 9):

We don't penalize users for lack of good behavior, [we use a positive reward system here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/).

> Badges exist to **reward and encourage the kind of positive behavior we want in our community**.

At least half this request won't work, because we're not going to strip your rep and brand you with a negative badge just for not being active...that's just not how we roll.

Comment: +1 That's also true! (I'm going to bookmark that.) :)

Comment: @ Nick : I knew that there was a "bad badge" and I award it for a question in stackoverflow: the  Tumbleweed badge! However, as I said in an edit, my suggestion can be accepted partially with only the "positive" bonus...

Answer (score 5):

For views (on your questions), we have:

1. (Bronze) **[Popular Question Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question)**: *Asked a question with 1,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.*
2. (Silver) **[Notable Question Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question)**: *Asked a question with 2,500 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.*
3. (Gold) **[Famous Question Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question)**: *Asked a question with 10,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.*

Now, if I got it right, you're asking to be awarded a badge, just because you visited N questions? I don't see how that could be considered a "merit", if we exclude the badges that are awarded because you visited the site: [Enthusiast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/39/enthusiast) (silver) and [Fanatic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic) (gold) badges.

Comment: @ Alenanno : well I consider a merit if someone read many questions without ask all times for something that someone already wrote...

Comment: @Filippo1980 Ok but how can you measure that? How do you know the difference (for me) between a question that I'm reading our of curiosity and one that I'm reading because it treats about my problem? It's not measurable.

Comment: @Filippo1980 - Simply _viewing_ a question doesn't imply anything about  _reading_ the question.

Comment: You are right, nobody can know why I open a certain question but I would tell you a thing: also the two badges that alenanno mentioned could be awarded simply opning for 3 seconds the site all days for XX days and nobody could check that!